# How to install XNA in Visual Studio 2014

Tags: asp.net

How can I install the templates and the the framework for XNA in Visual Studio 2014?

I found this page here that helps installing the XNA framework in Visual Studio 2013, but they do not offer any downloads for Visual Studio 2014?

I know that XNA is not developed anymore by Microsoft, but it is a really great Framework that I need to use in Future.

Comment: Microsoft never has a product called Visual Studio 2014.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could tell, XNA has been completely discontinued by Microsoft and is no longer downloadable.

However, there is another framework that uses the exact same style and .dll files as XNA. It's called MonoGame. I switched over from XNA to MonoGame and love it. When you start out, you probably won't even be able to tell the difference between the two frameworks. The downloads can be found [here](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/). They will automatically install as an extension to Visual Studio 2017 or 2015.

Hope I could help,

-GHC